# jquery click executed multiple times

Tags: jquery, setinterval

My problem is with correctly *toggle*-ing the state of some buttons. I use **jquery click** events. And I'm sorry for the long post, but I don't know where the problem is and don't want to accidentally miss it. I searched for similar questions but none seemed to fix my problem.

I start rendering a *div* containing some tasks I want to do for today. And I want to be able to toggle them as being done or not.

```js
{
    $('#currentDiv').hide();
    rewriteDivFromScratch();
    $('#eachday').show();
}
```

Where the **rewriteDivFromScratch** adds button divs to **HTML**:

```html
<div id="eachday"> .. </div>
    <div id="button-0" class="button"> <button class="btn btn-mini"> .. </button> </div>
    ..
    <div id="button-7" class="button"> <button class="btn btn-mini"> .. </button> </div>
```

```js
function rewriteDivFromScratch() {
    el = $("#eachday");

    // get the HTML divs from Handlebars templating compilation
    // they're OK, I checked with inspector

    // This renderes nicely, no problem here.
    el.html(html);
}
```

I add a **click event** for buttons to toggle in the same file with those above:

```
$('.btn-mini').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);  // the <button />
    el.toggleClass('btn-inverse');
}
```

And I get **no toggleing** effect..

Now, I suppose this happens because there is not **.btn-mini** class by the time the $(..).click **executes**. This is why I added a **setInterval** like so:

```js
var intervalId; // it's global in my js file
function rewriteDivFromScratch() {
    ...
    // This renderes nicely, no problem here.
    el.html(html);
    intervalId = setInterval(check); // this fires only once, so seems OK
}
```

```js
var check = function() {
    $('.btn-mini').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var el = $(e.currentTarget);  // the <button />

        if (el.length)
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        else
            return;

        // It executes this toggle more than **15** times per
        // click on button.. Now, why is that?
        el.toggleClass('btn-inverse');
    }
};
```

As I've said in the above last comment, my problem is that that part gets executed multiple times, not a fixed number of times per refresh, in order to find a pattern or something.

The above js code is in a single 'app.js' which I simply include in my index.html like any other script.

Comment: also, if you have suggestions to improving my js coding, please tell. I want to write good code, and will soon try to migrate all my code to mvc, with backbone. Thanks!

Comment: You know there is a jQuery.toggle() right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use jquery's 'live' for a 'delegated event', which will also work whenever new buttons are inserted into the document:

```
$('.button').live('click', function(){
  //button clicked
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/live/ for further explanations of how 'live' works.

Comment: thanks! this worked. I don't know though why with my old code with setInterval the strange behavior was going on.